# How to save buffer data into a file using browser javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I have a pdf buffer data coming from my nodeJS backend, something like..

"%PDF-1.5
%����..."

How can I save this into a file using browser's javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a file on the NodeJS end, and then download the file using javascript. That is probably the best way, as javascript does not have access to writing to the file system.

Comment: I don't want to waste my server space, is there a way to download it directly on the front end ?

Comment: Try this, but there are some limitations. http://cwestblog.com/2014/10/21/javascript-creating-a-downloadable-file-in-the-browser/

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for late reply,You can do piping like this:

```
    filepath = 'test.pdf';

    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error)
                throw new Error(error);

        }).on('end', function () {
            return callback(filepath);
        }).on('error', function (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }).pipe(dest);
    }
```